# Can QGIS import Multipatch geometry type?

Tags: qgis, geometry, 3d, multipatch

can QGIS import multipatch 3d geometry type? What is the data structure of multipatch how computer record and draws it ? Is it solid or not??

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 6):

In QGIS try using GDAL/OGR to read shapefiles and in [GDAL: ESRI Shapefile](http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html)

> MultiPatch files are read and each patch geometry is turned into a multi-polygon representation with one polygon per triangle in triangle fans and meshes.

Example with a multipatch shapefile from [Los Angeles County GIS Data Portal: County owned buildings (2D and 3D models)](http://egis3.lacounty.gov/dataportal/2010/03/19/3d-models-of-county-owned-buildings/)

[image]

Qgis geometries do not manage z data but the resulting shapefile has 3D points.

Control in Python with [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html)

```py
import fiona
c = fiona.open(fiona.open("4_134.shp"))
print len(c) #number of features
1 
first = c.next()
print first['geometry']
{'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': [[[(6441533.5786491064, 1773184.9825320288, 64.642633985851333),(6441533.7805271028,1773185.1838124467, 64.641312628761582), (6441534.0559996143, 1773185.2571860906, 64.640093677226531), ...]]]}
# first polygon coordinates
print first['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
[[(6441533.5786491064, 1773184.9825320288, 64.642633985851333), (6441533.7805271028, 1773185.1838124467, 64.641312628761582), (6441534.0559996143, 1773185.2571860906, 64.640093677226531), (6441534.3312539924, 1773185.1829925482, 64.639303741264058), (6441534.5325360633, 1773184.9811119298, 64.639154488561459), (6441534.6059124451, 1773184.7056379635, 64.639685900522167), (6441534.5317219961, 1773184.4303836888, 64.640755596299101), (6441534.3298439989, 1773184.2291032772, 64.642076947277815), (6441534.0543714939, 1773184.1557296331, 64.64329589881288), (6441533.7791171158, 1773184.2299231694, 64.644085828664316), (6441533.5778350448, 1773184.4318038002, 64.644235096644493), (6441533.504458664, 1773184.7072777662, 64.643703672461726), (6441533.5786491064, 1773184.9825320288, 64.642633985851333)]]
```

Comment: thank you for answer so, how computer record and draw multipatch features? could you give some detailed information about it?

Comment: in 2D or 3D ? In 2D you can convert  the multipolygon geometry  to individual polygons. In 3D, with QGIS, you cannot.